# How to Iterate over pandas dataframe and chunk test data based on condition

Tags: pandas, dataframe, timestamp

I am attempting to use pandas for some dataprocessing.

I have large datasets of timestamped test data. Data is continuously recorded in our tests, and when we start a test, it sets a value to '1' for the duration of the test.

I am looking for a way to iterate over this test data and chunk out the data for each individual test into smaller dataframes.

Psuedocode:

```
For each ROW in BIG_DATA

  IF is_test == 0, do nothing

  IF is_test == 1, add row to TestN_Dataframe, continue until row is reached where is_test == 0
```

There is always a chunk of rows between each test where is_test == 0. At the end, I would like to have a unique dataframe for each unique test in the data set.

Comment: you are starting with wrong concept - iteration.  Change your concept to sets,  use masks to identify sub-sets you want and it's simple

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on using masks to identify the subsets? I could work on the idea of using sets to separate out the individual tests once I had somehow marked each as different, but how would I group each test?